# JavaFX BarChart bars align

Tags: javafx, bar-chart, javafx-8

Now I have something like this

[image]

and I don't understand why bars go left instead stay at center of tick. Some hint to fix it?

Comment: Belated, but for those who stumble on this problem check [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116867/align-bars-with-bar-labels-in-jfreechart

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the gap between bars to 0

```
    BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    chart.setBarGap(0.0);
```

The effect you see in your example is the result of the default implementation of the BarChart. 
Because the CategoryAxis accepts more than 1 XYChart.Series of XYChart.Data. Meaning that more than 1 bar can be displayed for each category. Seeing as how they display the bars next to each other, the logical consequence is that the first bar be placed left (Like in your result). By simply setting the bar gap to 0, you should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put negative values in setBarGap in order to center bar in tick.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I wanted to comment below author's post but I could not since I do not have enough reputations. Thanks