# How to align bar and corresponding label properly in Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I am working on a jasper report in which I am creating a bar chart. For individual bar separate series expression has been created. But in my case the labels on x-axis and bars are not aligned properly.

Here I posted generated graph:
[image]

Part of my jrxml file is mentioned here:

```
<categoryDataset>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["CalWORKS"]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["CalWORKS"]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{calworks_count}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Immediate Need CW"]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Immediate Need CW"]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{calworks_immediate_need_count}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["CalFresh"]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["CalFresh"]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{calfresh_count}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Expedited CF"]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Expedited CF"]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{calfresh_expedited_count}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Medi-Cal"]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Medi-Cal"]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{medical_count}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Immediate Medi-Cal"]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Immediate Medi-Cal"]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{medical_immediate_need_count}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
            </categoryDataset>
```

Also I am using customizer which is given here:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot)chart.getPlot();
    BarRenderer barRenderer = (BarRenderer)plot.getRenderer();
    Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12);
    plot.getRenderer().setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER));
    barRenderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
    barRenderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(font);
    barRenderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    plot.getDomainAxis().setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2);
    plot.getRangeAxis().setUpperMargin(plot.getRangeAxis().getUpperMargin() + 0.1);
    barRenderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(5.0d);
    //barRenderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.9f);
    barRenderer.setItemMargin(0.0f);

}
```

I tried to adjust barWidth value but its not working. Also I made labels to split into two lines which is also not working. Is there any way to achieve this?

Also I am not able to increase the width of bars. Using customizer how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quasi-duplicate of this post: [Align bars with bar labels in Jfreechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116867/align-bars-with-bar-labels-in-jfreechart)

In your case, of course, the solution is to reformat your xml file to leave only one series (among six categories):

```
       <categoryDataset>
            <categorySeries>
                <seriesExpression><![CDATA["series1"]]></seriesExpression>
                <categoryExpression><![CDATA["CalWORKS"]]></categoryExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{calworks_count}]]></valueExpression>
            </categorySeries>
            <categorySeries>
                <seriesExpression><![CDATA["series1"]]></seriesExpression>
                <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Immediate Need CW"]]></categoryExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{calworks_immediate_need_count}]]></valueExpression>
            </categorySeries>
            ...
```

Comment: If single series then I won't be able to color them using different color. Am i right?

Comment: Correct. Unless you use a custom renderer, as in: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo3differentcolorswithinaseries.htm

Comment: Ok. That is something new I came to know now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I created custom renderer to get my requirement fulfilled :)